# Could "Panim Chadashot" be fulfilled by FaceTime/ Skype?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, technology, sheva-brachos, maseches-kesubos

In Maseches [Kesuvos 7b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.7b.11?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he) we learn about the requirement of "*panim chadashot*" (lit: new faces) for every day of *sheva brachos* (codified in [Even Ha'Ezer 62:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.62.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Could the requirement of *panim chadashot* be fulfilled if a previously nonpresent person were to FaceTime/ Skype etc into the couple's *sheva brachos*?

Comment: Why would you think yes? Since when does a video call create a halachic reality?

Comment: I think Chacham Ovadia held that seeing Kotel on kotel cam may patur one from doing kriyah if they visit the kotel within 30 days from seeing it on kotel cam,since it's a safek bracha lahakel @mdjava.  Regarding sheva brachos the inyan is to be part if the simcha some say he has to eat as well, so Skype wpuld not really help for anything.

Comment: @MDjava looking at previous questions answered on here, there's a variety of yes/no answers https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=skype

Comment: It's plausible that while they can't be panim chadashot, they can still count as guests for asher bara

Answer (score 1):

The Pischei Teshuva in the  quoted Shulchan Aruch EH 62,7 in the name of the Zecher LeAvraham says that the [Human] Ponim Chadasos have to be men who are present and can join a *minian*:

> בס' זכור לאברהם שכ' אשה לא חשיבא פ"ח ד**אין פנים חדשות אלא למי שראוי להמנות בעשרה של ברכת חתנים** כ"כ מהר"ר בצלאל פ"ק דכתובות ד' ז' ולפ"ז ה"ה עבדים וקטנים לא חשיבי פ"ח ע"ש.

Even though the Shulchan Aruch 62,8 says that Shabbos and Yom tov are *Ponim Chadashos* although they are not physical, this is to do with the the extra food that we eat in respect of presence of the *Shechina* that Accompanies Shabbos and Yomtov, see commentaries there:

> אמרינן במדרש מזמור שיר ליום השבת אמר הקב"ה פנים חדשות באו לכאן ודרך להרבות בשבת שמחה ומנות

And even though the Bach (62) Brings a Minhag that on *Shalosh Seudos* the Choson says a Dvar Torah and we say *Sheva Brochos*, the reason is because people are bringing more food to show their love respect for the Torah being said together with the presence of Shabbos:

> ובמנות ועיקרי הקהל באים לסעודה לכבוד הדרשה שדורש החתן ומרבים במתנות להחתן אחר הדרשה הוי פנים חדשות ומברכין ז' וכ"כ במנהגים

But with regards to skype, it cannot replicate humans or Shabbos or Yom Tov (or cause the Divine presence to dwell among ourselves) in order to warrant more food. So human presence either via medium of a screen or other forms of imagination or projection is not *Ponim Chdashos*.

Comment: Who says that this is because they have to be present at the minyan? Maybe it's talking about the chashivus they need to have, and that they have to be "fit" to partake in the minyan...?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות you are very wise which is why you will understand me if i tell you that purely having Chashivus does not make you a presence when you are not there as a human, otherwise the Shulchan Aruch would have said not only is Shabbos Ponim Chadashos, but also any Choshuv person that the Chosson and Kallah imagine being there is counted as Ponim chadashos. It says pretty clearly in the Pischei teshuva whoever cannot join in the **Minian** is not counted, you'll agree that thre you cannot imagine a minian or use a tv screen with nine other faces.

Comment: I'm not sure what argument you are making.  Truth is, I am playing with you a little bit in asking these questions, but it's to get to a point, which is to realize that the basis for these questions is the Machlokes Rishonim here, not an odd diyuk in an acharon who you clearly haven't heard of before. So I would counter with another question: Let's say that the person left before benching (before Sheva Brachos). May the Chosson and Kallah still say the brachos?

Comment: also, what about a derashah? Can that count in a minyan?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות in polite terms you want to say a tv is ponim Chadashos based on the fact that a Drasha of Torah according to some Rishonim which irepresents the Shechina Betoch Arba Amos SHel Halacha . well this warrants a downvote from yourself and i'm sure you expect a pat on the back to for your sharp anylitical skills.

Comment: no, no, no.  As I said before, you shouldn't be bringing raayas from diyukim in acharonim to answer a shailah like this when you can explain it all based on the major machlokos in rishonim. I don't think a tv is ponim chadashos at all, nor do I think it is similar to a derashah or shabbos. I'm simply trying to point out the flaws in your reasoning and diyuk from a borderline source.

Comment: Bli Neder I'll post a solid answer in a few hours.

Comment: I would never do that, although I routinely downvote what I consider subpar answers. I'm learning this sugyah now briefly, so I looked at these questions. If you would like to post a good sourced answer that incorporates the major halachic discussions, I'm happy to share a summary I found online. If you incorporate it, I'll be happy to reverse my downvote.

Comment: See [http://beinenu.com/sites/default/files/alonim/211_05_79.pdf] pages 86 and 87

Comment: @רבותמחשבות your link seems to not work

Comment: bizarre. Try https://www.google.ca/search?source=hp&ei=a07nXNyJF4-qsgW63LCQAQ&q=http%3A%2F%2Fbeinenu.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Falonim%2F211_05_79.pdf%5D&oq=http%3A%2F%2Fbeinenu.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Falonim%2F211_05_79.pdf%5D&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.3...5086.5086..5829...0.0..0.206.206.2-1......0....2j1.......8..41.baMaNY5A8ug